# ImageMagick works as root, but not with PHP

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, php, imagemagick

I am brand-spanking-new at Ubuntu. I have my first webserver at Digital Ocean, build with Serverpilot.

I just installed ImageMagick and it works when I SSH into the machine.

However, when I try to `exec` the same command with PHP, it doesn't work.

My best guess is that PHP doesn't have the nessesary rights to write the new file, but I may be wrong - as I said, I'm a n00b... :-)

Comment: What are the permissions of the folder?

Comment: How can I see that?

Comment: do you get an error message, when running the php command? If yes, please [edit] your question and include it.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to exec imagemagick in php. php has an image-magic library. It also has GD, a much better image processing library. Read the [php imagemagick documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) for a start.

Comment: I needed to make a gradientmap, which I can't in GD (AFAIK).

Comment: this thread do anything for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276780/making-an-image-greyscale-with-gd-library im not real familiar with what a gradient maps is, but I know the are a bunch of ways to read pixel values a record them and or manipluate them with math. Im wondering of the html5 canvas element has the functionality you desire.